How can immaterial soul exist without matter but immaterial redness can't?
So as the title says Aristotle and Aquinas held that soul which is substantial form of living things can exist even after separation from body. This is because soul is taken as immaterial substantial form, but doesn't it mean that "redness" or other forms that are immaterial can exist independently without matter?

Who says they can't?

Like many people, I take issue with "souls can exist". Also, the colour of objects is a combination of its physical makeup that makes light bounce off of it in specific ways, as well as light travelling through space and hitting our eyes, and our eyes and brain processing that in certain ways. So that (also) seems perfectly material.

In the sense that souls can exist "without matter" in Aristotle, redness also can, it is when either is extracted by some intellect and 'resides' there. Divine Nous is the presumed repository for souls after death, although Aristotle is very obscure. Aquinas distinguished "material" forms like redness, parts of passive essence, and "substantial" forms like souls, with active causal powers or esse. Even so, his disembodied souls have only deficient existence and are not fully human in such state, see How can the soul be a form.

Thomas Aquinas Emulator based on ChatGPT has an answer which can be interactively explored in a dialogue with the chatbot.
